# jQuery Sortable - drag and drop multiple items

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have the following code, which allows user to drag and drop from one list to another. Now, how can I allow the user to select and drag & drop multiple items?

Something like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/T68Fn/

I have tried to incorporate the code from the jsfiddle in, but can't really get it to work. Any help is highly appreciated.

Please help me out. Thank you very much.

HTML

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="maincontainer">
   <div id="navtoplistline">&nbsp;</div>
      <div id="contentwrapper">
        <div id="maincolumn">
           <div class="text">
            <hr />
            <div class="listBlock">
                    <h2>Available</h2>

                <ul id="sortable1" class='droptrue'>
                    <li class="ui-state-default" id="article_1">Article #1</li>
                    <li class="ui-state-default" id="article_2">Article #2</li>
                    <li class="ui-state-default" id="article_3">Article #3</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="listBlock">
                    <h2>My Articles</h2>

                <ul id="sortable2" class='droptrue'></ul>
            </div>
            <br clear="both" />
            <p>Which articles, in which order?:
                <br />
                <input type="text" id="postOrder" name="postOrder" value="" size="30" />
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.listBlock {
  float: left;
}
#sortable1, #sortable2 {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-right: 100px;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#sortable1 li, #sortable2 li {
  cursor: move;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 250px;
  background: none;
  background-color: white;
}
```

SCRIPT

```
    $(function() {
        $("ul.droptrue").sortable({
            connectWith: 'ul',
            opacity: 0.6,
            update : updatePostOrder
        });

        $("#sortable1, #sortable2").disableSelection();
        $("#sortable1, #sortable2").css('minHeight',$("#sortable1").height()+"px");
        updatePostOrder();
    });

    function updatePostOrder() { 
        var arr = [];
      $("#sortable2 li").each(function(){
        arr.push($(this).attr('id'));
      });
      $('#postOrder').val(arr.join(','));
  }
```

Comment: youre gonna wanna look at Handles.. this is the code you should be focusing on in the example: 
        `start: function(e, ui) {
            ui.helper.addClass(selectedClass);
        },` search for Helper/handle jquery sortable

Answer (score 13):

One way is to create a custom [helper](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-helper) with the selected items, hide the items while dragging and manually append the selected items upon [receive](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-receive).

Here's my attempt:

css

```
.selected {
  background:red !important;
}
.hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

script:

```
 $('.droptrue').on('click', 'li', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
 });

 $("ul.droptrue").sortable({
    connectWith: 'ul.droptrue',
    opacity: 0.6,
    revert: true,
    helper: function (e, item) { //create custom helper
        if(!item.hasClass('selected'))
           item.addClass('selected');
        // clone selected items before hiding
        var elements = $('.selected').not('.ui-sortable-placeholder').clone();
        //hide selected items
        item.siblings('.selected').addClass('hidden');
        var helper = $('<ul/>');
        return helper.append(elements);
    },
    start: function (e, ui) {
        var elements = ui.item.siblings('.selected.hidden').not('.ui-sortable-placeholder');
        //store the selected items to item being dragged
        ui.item.data('items', elements);
    },
    receive: function (e, ui) {
        //manually add the selected items before the one actually being dragged
        ui.item.before(ui.item.data('items'));
    },
    stop: function (e, ui) {
        //show the selected items after the operation
        ui.item.siblings('.selected').removeClass('hidden');
        //unselect since the operation is complete
        $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    },
    update: updatePostOrder
});
```

```js
$(function () {
    $('.droptrue').on('click', 'li', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    });

    $("ul.droptrue").sortable({
        connectWith: 'ul.droptrue',
        opacity: 0.6,
        revert: true,
        helper: function (e, item) {
            console.log('parent-helper');
            console.log(item);
            if(!item.hasClass('selected'))
               item.addClass('selected');
            var elements = $('.selected').not('.ui-sortable-placeholder').clone();
            var helper = $('<ul/>');
            item.siblings('.selected').addClass('hidden');
            return helper.append(elements);
        },
        start: function (e, ui) {
            var elements = ui.item.siblings('.selected.hidden').not('.ui-sortable-placeholder');
            ui.item.data('items', elements);
        },
        receive: function (e, ui) {
            ui.item.before(ui.item.data('items'));
        },
        stop: function (e, ui) {
            ui.item.siblings('.selected').removeClass('hidden');
            $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        },
        update: updatePostOrder
    });

    $("#sortable1, #sortable2").disableSelection();
    $("#sortable1, #sortable2").css('minHeight', $("#sortable1").height() + "px");
    updatePostOrder();
});

function updatePostOrder() {
    var arr = [];
    $("#sortable2 li").each(function () {
        arr.push($(this).attr('id'));
    });
    $('#postOrder').val(arr.join(','));
}
```

```css
.listBlock {
    float: left;
}
#sortable1, #sortable2 {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-right: 100px;
    background: #eee;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#sortable1 li, #sortable2 li {
    color:black;
    cursor: move;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 250px;
    background: none;
    background-color: white;
}
.selected {
    background:red !important;
}
.hidden {
    display:none !important;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="maincontainer">
    <div id="navtoplistline">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="contentwrapper">
        <div id="maincolumn">
            <div class="text">
                <hr />
                <div class="listBlock">
                     <h2>Available</h2>

                    <ul id="sortable1" class='droptrue'>
                        <li id="article_1">Article #1</li>
                        <li id="article_2">Article #2</li>
                        <li id="article_3">Article #3</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="listBlock">
                     <h2>My Articles</h2>

                    <ul id="sortable2" class='droptrue'></ul>
                </div>
                <br clear="both" />
                <p>Which articles, in which order?:
                    <br />
                    <input type="text" id="postOrder" name="postOrder" value="" size="30" />
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/shLQE/)

Comment: Great info! Really helped with answering this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38221956/jquery-ui-sorting-multiple-table-row-at-once