# Sortable multi-select

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I know there are several ways to have a 'sortable' multiselect, such as:

https://github.com/yanickrochon/jquery.uix.multiselect

However, I wasn't able to find a sortable multi-select that actually looks and works like a multiselect. For example:

[image]

Is there currently a plug-in or gist of code that provides a way to drag-and-drop sort within a multi-select interface?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24467682/2333214) might help